# Why is private constructor still visible in case class?

Tags: scala, access-modifiers, case-class, companion-object, private-constructor

I want to hide constructor in one class along with its fields and only create instances using a companion object, but I can't achieve that. I have scala 2.13.3 and it's based on java 8. Here is a code sample:

**A.scala**

```
package X

object A {
  def apply(x: Int): A = A(Seq(x))
}

case class A private(private val s: Seq[Int])
```

**B.scala**

```
package Y

import X.A

class B {
  val b = A(Seq.empty)
}
```

And although I wanted to make only `apply(x:Int)` visible this code compiles so the private constructor is also visible. How can I change this code to work as I expected?

Comment: If you want the constructor and the fields to be private, you may want to use a normal class instead of a case class. That way you do not need to hide the default apply in the companion object. Also, the `copy` method makes the constructor public again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the method `A.apply(Seq[Int])` private too

*A.scala*

```
package X

object A {
  def apply(x: Int): A = A(Seq(x))
  private def apply(s: Seq[Int]): A = new A(s) // make explicit and private instead of auto-generated and public
}

case class A private(private val s: Seq[Int])
```

*B.scala*

```
package Y

import X.A

class B {
  //val b = A(Seq.empty) // doesn't compile
}
```

Here the line `val b = A(Seq.empty)` produces error

```
Error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [A]Seq[A]
 required: Int
```

i.e. the method `A.apply(Seq[Int])` is not visible from `B`.

Comment: Thanks! This naturally works. But somehow here https://github.com/combust/mleap/blob/master/mleap-core/src/main/scala/ml/combust/mleap/core/types/StructType.scala#L11 guys managed to achieve this without making private apply. I can't call `StructType(Seq, Map, Map)` although I don't know why.

Comment: @xan No, `StructType(Seq, Map, Map)` seems to be accessible: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xxK1MUclTGOPjGcimFYtlg Write code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @xan If you write just `StructType(Seq(), Map(), Map())` types are inferred as `StructType.apply(Seq[Nothing], Map[Nothing, Nothing], Map[Nothing, Nothing])` and there is no such `apply` method among overloaded versions.

Comment: @xan Funny, `val b = A(Seq.empty)` produces `found: [A]Seq[A]; required: Int` while `val b = A(Seq())` produces `found: Seq[Nothing]; required: Int`.

Comment: That's interesting. Seems like nullary methods are treated differently. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NO7j9zgbQ82Z7Zmdabmg4g

Comment: They're all inferred to `Seq[Nothing]` in Dotty, though: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/S10JSz44QGSNd6cTPJ4ltQ